# Is there anything I can do instead of $("input:radio").change(function() {} to activate AJAX when a certain radio input is clicked?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, function

I have this loop that loops through my database table `tvshows` to get the names of  the T.V shows and output them to the screen with a radio input:

```
<div style="width: 200px;">

  <div>
    <?php

        $query = "SELECT distinct(title), (id) from tvshows";
        $featured = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($featured)) { ?>

                 <div class="list-group-item checkbox" style="  background- 
                 color: #f4f4f4;">

                    <label ><input type="radio" name="re" 
                    class="common_selector collection" style="" value="<?php 
                    echo $row['title']; ?>" id='sale'>   <?php echo 
                    $row['title']; ?></label>
                </div>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the AJAX:

```
 $("input:radio").change(function() {
            var product_id = $(this).attr('id');    
            var coll = $(this).attr('value'); 
            var action = "check";

      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $.ajax({
                url:"../PHP_Scripts/fetch_data.php",
                method: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data:{
                    coll:coll, action:action, product_id:product_id
                },
                success:function(data){
                    $('#product_wrapper').html(data);
                    alert("success");

                }
          });
 });
```

It's the `$("input:radio").change(function() {}` that is my issue. To summarise why this problem is happening: the script `PHP_Scripts/fetch_data.php` activates every time the radio input is changed. Its function is to output the products based off of which radio button is clicked. It's an issue because the `PHP_Scripts/fetch_data.php` also contains some AJAX that adds the product to the cart, so when the radio input changes, and you try to add a product to the cart, the product gets added to the cart the same amount of times as the input has been changed. So if you check a radio input 3 times, then click the button that adds a product to the cart, it will be added 3 times.

The reason I didn't paste every page is that the issue just one line: `$("input:radio").change(function() {}`. Does anyone know an alternative I can use to activate the AJAX when say, a certain input is checked?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Do you want the ajax to be called every time a input changes, or not? If not, when exactly do you want it to run, and when not?

Comment: I'd like the AJAX to be called when a certain radio is checked. So say you check the "Game of Thrones" radio, I'd like some AJAX to send to a script that outputs the "Game of Thrones" products.

Comment: How is this certain radio different from the ones where ajax shouldn't be called? Are they in a different place?

Comment: @iagowp To make them different, I added: value="<?php echo $row['title']; ?>" so that each radio's value would be different. I could also add value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" so that the id accords to the id in the database if need be.

Comment: But how do you know if you want to call the ajax or not?

Comment: @iagowp If the user checked, for example the input that had the value of "Game of Thrones", I'd want it to execute some AJAX code that sent it to a script that prints all of the "Game of Thrones" products. I just don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: Sounds like you should have a separate "add to cart" button, rather than doing this immediately when the user clicks on the button for the item.

Comment: I agree with Barmar. This sounds like a design issue. The radio buttons let the user choose an item, but of course people can change their mind and click the radio buttons multiple times. You don't want to add the product to the cart every time. You should have a separate way for the user to indicate that the current choice is their final choice, such as an Add to Cart button or similar.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk I can't believe it was something so simple. I didn't even think the solution would be as easy as this, my mind was jumping to such convoluted solutions. I literally just had to change the class name of the script add to cart button so it wasn't the same as the normal add to cart button.

Comment: @barner see above. Thank you both!